# How to just keep punctuation with a string in python?

Tags: python, string

I want create a catalog of all logs, so I just want keep all punctuation and remove all other chars which include CJK and others.

for example:

```
s = "aaa; sf = fa = bla http://wa"
```

expected output is

```
;==://
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
>>> from string import letters, digits, whitespace, punctuation
>>> s = "aaa; sf = fa = bla http://wa"
>>> s.translate(None, letters+digits+whitespace)
';==://'
```

or `regex`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^{}]+'.format(punctuation),'',s)
';==://'
```

**Timing comparisons:**

```
>>> s = "aaa; sf = fa = bla http://wa"*1000
>>> %timeit s.translate(None,letters+digits+whitespace)
10000 loops, best of 3: 171 us per loop                  #winner
>>> r1 = re.compile(r'[^{}]+'.format(punctuation))
>>> r2 = re.compile(r'[\w\s]+')
>>> %timeit r1.sub('',s)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.64 ms per loop
>>> %timeit r2.sub('',s)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.31 ms per loop
```

Comment: +1 for profiling; comparison with a compiled regular expression would be more fair.

Comment: string.translate can't remove none-ascii chars, but Regex can.

Answer (score 3):

Using a regular expression:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[\w\s]+', '', "aaa; sf = fa = bla http://wa")
';==://'
```

Compiling can buy some performance, even for such a simple pattern...

```
>>> %timeit re.sub(r'[\w\s]+', '', "aaa; sf = fa = bla http://wa")
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.78 us per loop

>>> e = re.compile(r'[\w\s]+')
>>> %timeit e.sub('', "aaa; sf = fa = bla http://wa")
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.91 us per loop
```

...but regular expression is no match for Ashwinis' solution using str.translate:

```
>>> %timeit "aaa; sf = fa = bla http://wa".translate(None,letters+digits+whitespace)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.31 us per loop
```